# Getting Forge 2-legged authentication using Cross request

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, autodesk-forge, 2-legged

I'm trying to create a simple html page to display a uploaded model to forge. For initialize the forge viewer it required the access-token. For request the access token I'm using the 2-legged oAuth on a Cross request(because I'm making the POST on different domain).But it keep getting error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource". Please some one can tell me what should I do to get the acces-token successfully.

Comment: for testing purpose you can use Chrome pluggin for that

Comment: I have already installed the "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin" extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, you cannot obtain a Forge Token via client-side scripting, it will throw this CORS error. This is by design.

I would recommend a simple server-side authentication, it's quite direct [to deploy this sample](https://github.com/augustogoncalves/forge-2leg.nodejs-template) locally:

1. Install NodeJS
2. Download the project
3. Set the variables with your ID & Secret
4. Run the project