# 403 - For bidden - Token does not have the privilege for this request. when trying to list the projects

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to list the projects by using the Account admin profile for this I've used below endpoint and used the Two-legged access token for my account ID. But It always has thrown error as 'Token does not have the privilege for this request. when trying to list the projects'

Comment: For this Endpoint, https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/:account-id/projects?limit=1&offset=0&sort=name

Comment: What request are You tried? Did U already got working example ???

Comment: @SkorpEN,  I have tried this Endpoint https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/:account/projects?limit=1&offset=0&sort=name also I don't have any working examples. So could you please guide me to get the correct results

Comment: Did U searched work working example for autodesk api ?? Did You know what is hq and do you have any account there ???

Comment: did U tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39911487/getting-forge-2-legged-authentication-using-cross-request?rq=1 this solution ???

Comment: Yes, I got the Two-legged access token in OAuth process. But I got the error While I try to list the project by using the Two-legged access token and my account-id.

Comment: I don't know about the term of  'hq'  Just I referred this  in this URL (doc) - https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-GET/

Comment: Are U using Postman ? Could you generate curl from it ???

Comment: start with the simplest request to that api, just to know that you are authenticated correctly.

Comment: Yes @SkorpEN,  I have tried this in Postman. Here I can authenticate this Endpoint - https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/gettoken and generated the access token after that, I have tried this endpoint 
 - https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/:account/projects?limit=1&offset=0&sort=name by a newly generated access token. But it's not working

Comment: Did U know your accountsId ???

Comment: Yeah. I know my account-id.  This is my sample call -  https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/e3d5ef8d-5c37-4b9d-925d-1e6d24753ace/projects?limit=1&offset=0&sort=name'

Comment: Could you export your request into curl format from postman ??? You could change token for privacy reason.

Comment: response :  {
    "developerMessage": "Token does not have the privilege for this request.",
    "moreInfo": "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/",
    "errorCode": "AUTH-010"
}

Comment: Now it's working for me. It's caused by scope variables. Thanks for your help